# Ng-Select in Ng-Select choose the next value from the first select box

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a situation where i have a select box that contains years (let's say 2014,2013,2012)
for each select box there are quarter for example: (2014->{q1},2013->{q1,q2,q3,q4})
i want a simple way to user Ng-option on Ng-Select that will do the following
1. the user is chose the year from the first dropdown
2. the second dropdown update by the chosen availability (if the user choose 2014 in the first select box he will get q1 as a single option in the second select box, but if the user will select 2013 in the first select box he will get q1,q2,q3,q4 at the second dropdown).

i'm also using the following json:

```
controller('PublishersCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {

$scope.publishers = [
        {year:'All'},
        {year:'2014',quarters: [{'Q1'},{'Q2'},{'Q3'}]},
        {year:'2013',quarters: [{'Q1'},{'Q2'},{'Q3'}]}},
    ];
```

}]

and this is my view code:

```
<section id="filter-and-summary">
<ul id="filters">
    <li>
        Year
        <select class="year" ng-model="publisher" ng-options="c.year for c in publishers">
        </select> |
    </li>
    <li>
        Quarter
        <select class="quarter" ng-model="publisher.quarters" data-ng-options="c.quarters for c in publishers">
        </select> |
    </li>
    <li>
```

I also attach a sample of how it should look like
please help me to understand what am i doning wrong,
it's also possible that my json is not defining right.

[image: example of the html]

Comment: `[{'Q1'},{'Q2'},{'Q3'}]}` isn't valid. Those are objects and should be in key/value pairs. You just have values.

Comment: what should show when `All` is selected ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oFANOsIR/3/edit)

**Markup:**

```
  <ul id="filters">
    <li>
      Year
      <select 
        class="year" 
        ng-model="selectedPublisher" 
        ng-options="item.year for item in publishers"
      >
      </select>
      |
    </li>
    <li ng-hide="selectedPublisher.year == 'All'">
      Quarter
      <select
        class="quarter" 
        ng-model="selectedQuarter" 
        ng-options="item for item in selectedPublisher.quarters"
      >
      </select>
      |
    </li>
  </ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.publishers = [
    {year:'All'},
    {year:'2014',quarters: ['Q1','Q2','Q3']},
    {year:'2013',quarters: ['Q1','Q2','Q3']}
  ];
  $scope.selectedPublisher = $scope.publishers[1];
  $scope.selectedQuarter = $scope.selectedPublisher.quarters[0];
});
```